# one button to stop all audio AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, audio, playback

please keep in mind that I am a newbie therefore not very experienced: I have several audio files playing triggered by a button, each time a button is pressed, all other sounds stop. Now I want to creadte a button which stops whatever is playing at the moment. Also, each time I press one of the button, the music doesn t start from the beginning, but from the point in time when it was interrupted. Thank you in advance, here is a snippet:

```
- (IBAction)playSound1 {
if ((self.sound2Player.playing) ||  (self.sound3Player.playing)|| (self.sound4Player.playing)||(self.sound5Player.playing)||(self.sound6Player.playing)||(self.sound7Player.playing))
    [self.sound2Player stop];
    [self.sound3Player stop];
    [self.sound4Player stop];
    [self.sound5Player stop];
    [self.sound6Player stop];
    [self.sound7Player stop];
    [self.sound2Player stop];

[self.sound1Player play];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this

```
- (IBAction)stopSound
 {

    [self.sound1Player stop];
    [self.sound2Player stop];
    [self.sound3Player stop];
    [self.sound4Player stop];
    [self.sound5Player stop];
    [self.sound6Player stop];
    [self.sound7Player stop];
    [self.sound2Player stop];
}
```

If you again want to play where it stop so why you are stopping the player use `[avPlayer pause]` to work instead of `[self.avPlayer stop];` then when you play again they will start from where you have stopped them.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Strange thing though, the stop command actually pauses them, that is, soundfiles start playng from the point where they were stopped, and do not cycle from the beginning...

Comment: Ok sorry I didn t know this, thank you again to both, have a good day